# Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless on ASUS TUF FX505DT have bad signal on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: wireless, asus

I have a dual boot on my ASUS TUF FX505DT.
On **Windows** wi-fi **signal** works **fine**.
On **Ubuntu**, the **signal** is very **weak** and the navigation is impossible(no navigation).
**How can I resolve it?
Thanks!**

I run this on terminal: **lspci -knn | grep Net -A3**
, as result:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:3041]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ce
    Kernel modules: wl, rtl8821ce
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso [1002:15d8] (rev c1)
```